# Fetch list of places such as "Toilet" in Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, fetch, mapbox

I would like to get the places (latitude and long) which is specific to toilet only, I don't know how I hope anyone can help me. I'm trying to learn Mapbox API.

Currently, I was able to display the map and a marker, I need to display places with toilets.

This is my current code:

```
class Annotation : AppCompatActivity(),OnMapClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAnnotationBinding
    private lateinit var mapboxMap: MapboxMap
    private lateinit var viewAnnotationManager: ViewAnnotationManager
    private val viewAnnotationViews = mutableListOf<View>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_annotation)

        viewAnnotationManager = binding.mapView.viewAnnotationManager
        mapboxMap = binding.mapView.getMapboxMap().apply {
            loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
                addOnMapClickListener(this@Annotation)
                binding.fabStyleToggle.setOnClickListener {
                    when (getStyle()?.styleURI) {
                        Style.MAPBOX_STREETS -> loadStyleUri(Style.SATELLITE_STREETS)
                        Style.SATELLITE_STREETS -> loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(this@Annotation, STARTUP_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        binding.fabReframe.setOnClickListener {
            if (viewAnnotationViews.isNotEmpty()) {
                val cameraOptions = viewAnnotationManager.cameraForAnnotations(viewAnnotationViews)
                cameraOptions?.let {
                    mapboxMap.flyTo(it)
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@Annotation, ADD_VIEW_ANNOTATION_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_view_annotation, menu)
        return true
    }
```